# Updating only relevant entities in aggregates with @ColumnTransformer

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, domain-driven-design

In our spring boot application, I am trying to save an aggregate, that consists of a root entity (ParentEntity) and a Set of child entities (ChildEntity).
The intention is, that all operations are done through the aggreate. So there is no need for a repository for ChildEntity, as the ParentEntity is supposed to manage all save or update operations.
This is how the Entities look like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tab_parent", schema = "test")
public class ParentEntity implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer parentId;
    
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    
    @Column(name = "created_datetime", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @ColumnTransformer(write = "COALESCE(?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)")
    private OffsetDateTime created;
    
    @Column(name = "last_modified_datetime", nullable = false)
    @ColumnTransformer(write = "COALESCE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,?)")
    private OffsetDateTime modified;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "ParentEntity")
    private Set<ChildEntity> children;
    
    // constructor and other getters and setters
        
    public void setChildren(final Set<ChildEntity> children) {
        this.children = new HashSet<>(children.size());
        for (final ChildEntity child : children) {
            this.addChild(child);
        }
    }
    
    public ParentEntity addChild(final ChildEntity child) {
        this.children.add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
        return this;
    }
    
    public ParentEntity removeChild(final ChildEntity child) {
        this.children.add(child);
        child.setParent(null);
        return this;
    }
    
}

@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "tab_child", schema = "test")
public class ChildEntity implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "child_id")
    private Integer childId;
    
    @Column(name = "language_id")
    private String languageId;
    
    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;
    
    @Column(name = "created_datetime", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @ColumnTransformer(write = "COALESCE(?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)")
    public OffsetDateTime created;
    
    @Column(name = "last_modified_datetime", nullable = false)
    @ColumnTransformer(write = "COALESCE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,?)")
    public OffsetDateTime modified;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", updatable = false)
    private ParentEntity parent;
    
    // constructor and other getters and setters    
    
    public ParentEntity getParent() {
        return this.parent;
    }
    
    public void setParent(final ParentEntity parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    
}
```

This is the store method to save or update the entities:

```
public Integer merge(final ParentDomainObject parentDomainObject) {
    final ParentEntity parentEntity =
            this.mapper.toParentEntity(parentDomainObject);
    final ParentEntity result = this.entityManager.merge(parentEntity);
    this.entityManager.flush();
    return result.getParentId();
}
```

And this is the store method to retrieve the aggregate by id:

```
public Optional<ParentDomainObject> findById(final Integer id) {
    return this.repo.findById(id).map(this.mapper::toParentDomainObject);
}
```

As you can see our architecture strictly separates the store from the service layer. So the service only knows about domain objects and does not depend on Hibernate Entites at all.
When updating either the child or the parent, firstly the parent is loaded. In the service layer, the domain object is updated (fields are set, or a child is added/removed).
Then the merge method (see code snippet) of the store is called with the updated domain object.

This works, but not completely as we want to. Currently every update leads to the parent and EVERY chhild entity being saved, even if all field remained the same. We added the @DynamicUpdate annotaton. Now we saw, that the "modified" field is the problem.
We use a @ColumnTransformer to have the database set the date. Now even if you call the services update method without changing anything, Hibernate generates a update query for EVERY object, which updates only the modified field.
The worst thing about that is, as every object is saved, every modified date changed as well to the current date. But we need information about exactly which object really changed and when.

Is there any way to tell hibernate, that this column should not be taken into account when deciding what to update. However of course, if a field changed, the update operation should indeed update the modified field.

**UPDATE:**

My second approach after @Christian Beikov mentioned the use of `@org.hibernate.annotations.Generated( GenerationTime.ALWAYS )`
is the following:

Instead of `@Generated` (which uses `@ValueGenerationType( generatedBy = GeneratedValueGeneration.class )`),
I created my own annotations, which use custom `AnnotationValueGeneration` implementations:

```
@ValueGenerationType(generatedBy = CreatedTimestampGeneration.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface InDbCreatedTimestamp {
}
```

```
public class CreatedTimestampGeneration
        implements AnnotationValueGeneration<InDbCreatedTimestamp> {
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(final InDbCreatedTimestamp annotation, final Class<?> propertyType) {
    }
    
    @Override
    public GenerationTiming getGenerationTiming() {
        return GenerationTiming.INSERT;
    }
    
    @Override
    public ValueGenerator<?> getValueGenerator() {
        return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean referenceColumnInSql() {
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getDatabaseGeneratedReferencedColumnValue() {
        return "current_timestamp";
    }
}
```

```
@ValueGenerationType(generatedBy = ModifiedTimestampGeneration.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface InDbModifiedTimestamp {
}
```

```
public class ModifiedTimestampGeneration
        implements AnnotationValueGeneration<InDbModifiedTimestamp> {
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(final InDbModifiedTimestamp annotation, final Class<?> propertyType) {
    }
    
    @Override
    public GenerationTiming getGenerationTiming() {
        return GenerationTiming.ALWAYS;
    }
    
    @Override
    public ValueGenerator<?> getValueGenerator() {
        return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean referenceColumnInSql() {
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getDatabaseGeneratedReferencedColumnValue() {
        return "current_timestamp";
    }
}
```

I use these annotations in my entities instead of the @ColumnTransformer annotations now.
This works flawlessly when I insert a new ChildEntity via addChild(), as now not all timestamps of all entities of the aggregate are updated anymore. Only the timestamps of the new child are set now.
In other words, the InDbCreatedTimestamp works as it should.

Sadly, the InDbModifiedTimestamp does not. Because of GenerationTiming.ALWAYS, I expected the timestamp to be generated on db level, everytime an INSERT **OR UPDATE** is issued. If I change a field of a ChildEntity and then save the aggregate, an update statement is generated only for this one database row, as expected. However, the `last_modified_datetime` column is **not** updated, which is surprising.
It seems that this is unfortunately still an open bug. This issue describes my problem precisely: [Link](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13290)

Can someone provide a solution how to get this db function executed on update as well (without using db triggers)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `@org.hibernate.annotations.Generated( GenerationTime.ALWAYS )` on these fields and use a database trigger or default expression to create the value. This way, Hibernate will never write the field, but read it after insert/update.

Overall this has a few downsides though (need the trigger, need a select after insert/update), so I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO/domain model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(ParentEntity.class)
@UpdatableEntityView
public interface ParentDomainObject {
    @IdMapping
    Integer getParentId();
    OffsetDateTime getModified();
    void setModified(OffsetDateTime modified);
    String getDescription();
    void setDescription(String description);
    Set<ChildDomainObject> getChildren();

    @PreUpdate
    default preUpdate() {
        setModified(OffsetDateTime.now());
    }

    @EntityView(ChildEntity.class)
    @UpdatableEntityView
    interface ChildDomainObject {
        @IdMapping
        Integer getChildId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`ParentDomainObject a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, ParentDomainObject.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<ParentDomainObject> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary! It also supports writing/mapping back to the persistence model in an efficient manner. Since it does dirty tracking for you, it will only flush changes if the object is actually dirty.

```
public Integer merge(final ParentDomainObject parentDomainObject) {
    this.entityViewManager.save(this.entityManager, parentDomainObject);
    this.entityManager.flush();
    return parentDomainObject.getParentId();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying and sorry for the late answer :) I am not sure how your example would set eg. the last_modified_datetime  column, as its missing in the interface. It seems to me that I still would need a database trigger, right? If not. Blaze Persistence may be a good match for us, and we might even use it in the future. Currently we are bound to hibernate, and I am close to a solution (see my updated question). It seems this solution does only not work because of an open bug in hibernate

Comment: You can either continue using a trigger or use an entity view pre-update lifecycle listener which is only called if there are dirty attributes. I updated the answer.